# How to list all structure definition and get the structure size in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb, structure, sizeof

ptype can be used when you know your structure name, but is there anyway to list all structure  definition rather than looking at source code?

print sizeof() can be used to print the structure size, but can we print all the structure size without knowing their name in advance?

Comment: Did you try [reading the manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols.html#Symbols)? :)

Comment: Recent GDB can be customized & scripted with Python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDITED:

gdb uses the struct 'tag' name for displaying details about the struct
    (field definitions, field values, sizeof, etc)
    (and a named struct definition is depreciated for defining structs)

so define the struct as

```
struct struct_t
{
    int field1;
    ...
};
```

then gdb can find/display all the details of the struct within the code

here is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct myStruct
{
    int alpha;
    int brovo;
};



 int main ( void )
 {
     struct myStruct structInstance;

     structInstance.alpha = 1;
     structInstance.brovo = 2;

     printf( "%d %d\n", structInstance.alpha, structInstance.brovo );
 } // end function: main
```

Lets say the resulting executable is named `untitled`

Then run `gdb` as in:

```
gdb untitled
br main
r
```

then show the contents of the struct:

```
p structInstance
```

which will output the following

```
$1 = {alpha = -8352, brovo = 32767}
```

Note that the `p` command was before the struct was initialized.

```
s
s
p structInstance
```

which will output:

```
$2 = {alpha = 1, brovo = 2}
```

Comment: This really doesn't say how to use gdb, and is strangely formatted.

Comment: one more detail,  when compiling, linking, (with `gcc`) use the parameter `-ggdb`